# Change grouped UITableView footer textLabel color

Tags: swift, uitableview

How to change the text color of the built-in `textLabel` of `UITablewViewHeaderFooterView`? I tried

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: footerId) else {
        return nil
    }
    footer.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
    return footer
}
```

but nothing happens. My table view is of `.grouped` style, if that matters

Comment: `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` but it returns nil. Previously, in iOS 8 and 9 try use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: footerId)`

Comment: It is probably your height for the footer not being returned correctly. Check what you return from `heightForFooterInSection`

Comment: The footer text is shown correctly, just can't change the text color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override `tableView:willDisplayFooter:forSection` for that. Somewhere between `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` and the latter, UIKit resets the textColor. Setting it in `willDisplayFooter` makes sure you change it last and therefore win :).

### Update

If you register a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass for your footer views, you may also override `willMove(toWindow:)` in that class and perform your changes there.

Another alternative is to set the `attributedText` property of the textLabel. UIKit won't mess with the color in that.

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much!